# React unable to read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, react-redux

Can't figure out where my mistake is. Not able to map through to display the list of blog comments. I'm using django and react. From the code below, I tried to assess each blog post with comments. But I'm not able to get the comment property from the blog. If I do something like {blog.title} I get the title of the blog back on the browser. Since comments are associated with each post I try to get different properties of comment from the blog object (just as I specified in the code below) but the Value I'm getting is undefined. and have the following blog post and blog comment models.

```
class BlogComment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="post_comment",  null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="user_comment", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username)

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
And the serializers for both models are:

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogComment
        fields = '__all__'

class BlogPostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = "__all__"

    def get_comments(self, obj):
        comments = obj.comment_set.all()
        serializer = CommentSerializer(comments, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

```
<h2>{blog.title}</h2>
<img src={blog.image} />
<div variant='flush'>
                    {blog.comments.map((comment) => (
                        <div key={comment.id}>
                            <strong>{comment.name}</strong>            
                            <p>{comment.dateCreated}</p>
                            <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
```

The comment API is functioning properly. In react, I'm able to add comments to each post using a form and the comments will appear in the database. But when I try to map through to display the comments of each blog post I get that error.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the length of an array before the map. Or you can use optional chaining.

like this `obj?.property`

```
<h2>{blog?.title}</h2>
<img src={blog?.image} />
<div variant='flush'>
                    {blog?.post?.comments.map((comment) => (
                        <div key={comment?.id}>
                            <strong>{comment?.name}</strong>            
                            <p>{comment?.dateCreated}</p>
                            <p>{comment?.comment}</p>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
```

Comment: I tried to check the array but I still get the same issue

Comment: have you tried optional chaining?